# Offset specification in R

Tags: r, offset, glm

Reading the description of glm in R it is not clear to me what the difference is between specifying a model offset in the formula, or using the offset argument.

In my model I have a response y, that should be divided by an offset term w, and for simplicity lets assume we have the covariate x. I use log link.

What is the difference between

```
glm(log(y)~x+offset(-log(w)))
```

and

```
glm(log(y)~x,offset=-log(w))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways are identical.

This can be seen in the documentation (the bold part):

> this can be used to specify an a priori known component to be included in the linear predictor during fitting. This should be NULL or a numeric vector of length equal to the number of cases. **One or more offset terms can be included in the formula instead or as well**, and if more than one is specified their sum is used. See model.offset.

The above talks about the `offset` argument in the `glm` function and says it can be included in the formula **instead or as well**.

A quick example below shows that the above is true:

Data

```
y <- sample(1:2, 50, rep=TRUE)
x <- runif(50)
w <- 1:50
df <- data.frame(y,x)
```

First model:

```
> glm(log(y)~x+offset(-log(w)))

Call:  glm(formula = log(y) ~ x + offset(-log(w)))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     3.6272      -0.4152  

Degrees of Freedom: 49 Total (i.e. Null);  48 Residual
Null Deviance:      44.52 
Residual Deviance: 43.69    AIC: 141.2
```

And the second way:

```
> glm(log(y)~x,offset=-log(w))

Call:  glm(formula = log(y) ~ x, offset = -log(w))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     3.6272      -0.4152  

Degrees of Freedom: 49 Total (i.e. Null);  48 Residual
Null Deviance:      44.52 
Residual Deviance: 43.69    AIC: 141.2
```

As you can see the two are identical.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that when you use offsets in the formula `glm(log(y)~x+offset(-log(w)))` and make your model this way, then if you later want to predict on your data, it will take into account values for `w` (the offset in this example), whereby if you include the offset in the `offset` argument, predictions will *not* account for the offsets.